# How do I re-enable a callback once I disabled it for rspec tests?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I have the following code, but my other test methods fail because the :before_save callback is not being triggered in separate tests.

```
 before do
      PropertyPerson.skip_callback :save, :before, :generate_match_input_names!, raise: false
    end

    describe :with_search_name_fuzzy do
      it 'finds the property_person' do
        property_person = property.property_people.create(person: person, match_input_search_names: ['Kamil Makski'])

        expect(PropertyPerson.with_search_name_fuzzy('KAM')).to be_present

      end
    end
```

Comment: Have you tried putting the `skip_callback` inside `describe :with_search_name_fuzzy` using a `before(:each)` block (or similar)?

Comment: Yes, I originally had that as well. I actually think it's affecting other tests in other classes as well

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`skip_callback` really isn't designed for temporary use like that.

A safer choice would be to have RSpec stub your callback method:

```
allow_any_instance_of(PropertyPerson).to receive(:generate_match_input_names!).and_return(true)
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think Rails allows you to re-enable callback easily. What you can do is you can redefine the called method to disable it:

```
before do
  class PropertyPerson
    alias :_orig_generate_match_input_names!, :generate_match_input_names!

    def generate_match_input_names!
      nil
    end
  end
end
```

and the reenable it

```
after do
  class PropertyPerson
    alias :generate_match_input_names!, :_orig_generate_match_input_names!
  end
end
```

The cool thing about `alias` is that it makes a copy of the method, not just the name. So you can use it to bring back it's original implementation without repeating the implementation itself (as you would need with `skip_callback` and `set_callback`)